# How to change the size of the images through the magnolia cms imaging module

Tags: helper, magnolia

I have put the jar file inside the library of my magnolia([https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/#nexus-search;classname~ImagingServlet](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/#nexus-search;classname%7EImagingServlet)), but when I invoke the url to return the cropped image, I get an error, if someone can help me.
[this is what appears to me[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grHZm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are either missing the `destinations` folder or user has no access to it. Alternatively you are missing imaging support for DAM - see more at various additional jars you might need in [documentation](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Modules/List-of-modules/Imaging-module.html#_imaging_support).

Also it seems you just copied thumbnail link from the admincentral, so perhaps you might want to [read more on using themes and predefined image variations](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Modules/List-of-modules/Imaging-module.html#_image_variations_in_a_theme).

Comment: I have everything you have told me, I have also reviewed it, and I do not understand why it does not generate the image or does not find it

Comment: Please provide the snippet of the code where you generate the link it doesn't seem correct. Without the code, it is impossible to help you any further.